# How to insert XAML into RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

A XAML text stored in database, how can I show its text in a RichTextBox after reading the XAML by XmlReader?

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
```

rt.Document = ???

------UPDATE-------------------
here is the xamlString contents:

```
<Section xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Left" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="User" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="13" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0"><Paragraph><Run xml:lang="fa-ir">Hello</Run><Run xml:lang="fa-ir" FontStyle="Italic">Hello1</Run><Run xml:lang="fa-ir" FontWeight="Bold">Testing</Run><Run xml:lang="fa-ir">Testing2</Run></Paragraph></Section>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Retrive a XAML text from RichTextBox:

```
private static string GetRTF(RichTextBox rt)
{
    TextRange range = new TextRange(rt.Document.ContentStart, rt.Document.ContentEnd);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    range.Save(stream, DataFormats.Xaml);
    string xamlText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    return xamlText;
}
```

---

### Render a XAML text into a RichTextBox:

```
private static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
    while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
        doc.Blocks.Add(sec.Blocks.FirstBlock);
    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call [`RichTextBox.AppendText(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to show formatted text (RTF) into RichTextBox. The question is updated.