# Convert XAML to FlowDocument to display in RichTextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have some HTML, which i am converting to XAML using the library provided by Microsoft

```
string t = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(mail.HtmlDataString,true);
```

now, from  [How to insert XAML into RichTextBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449121/how-to-insert-xaml-into-richtextbox) i am using the following:

```
private static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
    System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
    while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
        doc.Blocks.Add(sec.Blocks.FirstBlock);
    return doc;
}
```

This however keeps crashing unfortunately =/ Does anyone have any clue on how to display XAML text in a RichTextBox please?

EDIT: Example of html i'm trying to convert

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Paragraph>Top stories for<LineBreak />Tuesday,<LineBreak />May 4, 2010</Paragraph></TableCell><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Paragraph><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://adverts.timesofmalta.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?zoneid=7" /></Paragraph></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" RowSpan="10"><Paragraph FontSize="17px">Latest News</Paragraph></TableCell><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Paragraph><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/local">News</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/code-breaker">Code breaker</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/persuni-li-spiccaw-il-habs-minhabba-kazijiet-ta-vat">106 in prison since 2004 for VAT violations</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/mumn-disappointed-over-deployment-of-nurses">MUMN disappointed over deployment of nurses</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/press-digest">Press digest</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/world-news">World News</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/new-iceland-volcano-ash-grounds-flights-in-ireland">Ash cloud returns: Ryanair cancels Malta flight from Dublin</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/man-arrested-over-ny-bomb-attempt-reports">Man arrested over NY bomb attempt: reports</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Table><TableRowGroup><TableRow><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" RowSpan="10"><Paragraph FontSize="17px">The Times<LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell><TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black"><Paragraph><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/local">News</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/injured-president-returns-from-china">Injured President returns from China</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/law-breakers-to-be-barred-from-public-contracts">VAT fraud - Law breakers to be barred from public contracts</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/warden-assaulted-on-parking-ticket">Warden 'assaulted' on parking ticket</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/against-the-law">Against the law?</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/local/linkin-park-the-kooks-for-isle-of-mtv-concert">Linkin Park, The Kooks for Isle of MTV concert</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/world-news">World News</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/mumbai-attacks-gunman-convicted">Mumbai attacks gunman convicted</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/ireland-britain-eye-new-ash-flight-bans">Ireland, Britain eye new ash flight bans</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/white-male-suspect-linked-to-times-square-car-bomb">White male suspect linked to Times Square car bomb</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/iranian-president-blasts-us-for-nuclear-threats">Iranian President blasts US for nuclear threats</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/world-news/strikes-to-disrupt-greek-flights-as-from-today">Strikes to disrupt Greek flights as from today</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/business">Business &amp; Finance</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/business/ecb-returns-to-variable-rate-tender-procedures">Money market report - week ended April 30 - ECB returns to variable rate tender procedures</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/business/new-chairman-for-volksbank-malta-ltd">New chairman for Volksbank Malta Ltd</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/business/daily-currency-report">Daily currency report</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/business/financial-news">Financial news</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/business/european-stocks-shake-off-early-jitters-and-gain-ground">Market overview - European stocks shake off early jitters and gain ground</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/sport">Sport</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/sport/valletta-part-with-obrien">Football - Valletta part with O'Brien</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/sport/title-clinching-goal-just-reward-for-ebullient-bajada">Football - BOV Premier League - Title-clinching goal just reward for ebullient Bajada</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/sport/draw-enough-for-sliema-to-secure-third-place">Football - BOV Premier League - Draw enough for Sliema to secure third place</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/sport/bov-premier-league-highlights">Football - BOV Premier League highlights</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/sport/mqabba-finish-on-a-high">Football - Mqabba finish on a high</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/opinion">Opinion</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/opinion/editorial">Editorial - Keeping to the right financial track</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/opinion/habitats-of-the-maltese-islands-7">One World - Habitats of the Maltese islands (7)</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/opinion/guaranteeing-our-heritages-future">Guaranteeing our heritage's future</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/opinion/mixed-data-on-environment">Mixed data on environment</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/opinion/an-issue-of-accountability">An issue of accountability</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><Span FontWeight="bold"><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/headlines/20100504/letters">Letters</Hyperlink></Span><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/letters/service-deserving-of-a-national-award">Service deserving of a national award</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/letters/vulgar-perception-of-latin-language">Vulgar perception of Latin language</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/letters/chemical-spray-used-on-potato-crops">Chemical spray used on potato crops</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/letters/blasted-from-the-past-1">Blasted from the past (1)</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><Hyperlink Foreground="#555555" NavigateUri="http://www.timesofmalta.com/articles/view/20100504/letters/blasted-from-the-past-2">Blasted from the past (2)</Hyperlink><LineBreak /><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></TableCell></TableRow></TableRowGroup></Table></FlowDocument>
```

Comment: On what line does it fail? With what exception?

Comment: On the line Section sec, sec is remaining null, hence crashing on while (sec.Blocks.Count >0 ) =/

Comment: I'm adding an sample of what i'm trying to put in a RichTextBox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume it crashes on `Add()` because you are adding a `FrameworkContentElement` which already has a logical parent. You must first remove a `Block` from its parent and only then add it to a different collection. Try this:

```
private static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
    System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    Section sec = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Section;
    FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
    while (sec.Blocks.Count > 0)
    {
        var block = sec.Blocks.FirstBlock;
        sec.Blocks.Remove(block);
        doc.Blocks.Add(block);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

## If your XAML already represents a FlowDocument

Then things are much simpler. Just do a:

```
    private static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
    {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;
    }
```

#### Usage

`richTextBox.Document = SetRTF(xamlString);`

Comment: unfortunately this is also crashing as Section sec is remaining null =/ I've added a sample of what i'm trying to convert

Comment: It appears your XAML string actually represents a `FlowDocument`. Then things are much simpler. Just do a `return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as FlowDocument;` and you're done.

Comment: Oh man. Thanks a lot again to you. U also saved me. This is very important when you are getting string data from the server with HTML tags (<b>, <p>, <i> etc.).

Comment: Thanks worked perfect! I used the HtmlToXamlConverter available as NuGet paket to convert a simple Html to a Xaml string and then your second solution to convert it to a FlowDocument and display in RichtTextBox

Answer (score 3):

or short

```
    private FlowDocument StringToFlowDocument(string s)
    {
        var xamlString = string.Format("<FlowDocument xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"><Paragraph>{0}</Paragraph></FlowDocument>", s);
        return XamlReader.Parse(xamlString) as FlowDocument;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static FlowDocument SetRTF(string xamlString)
  {
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xamlString);
        System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        FlowDocument doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
        return doc;
  }
```