# Load .txt file into FlowDocument

Tags: c#, richtextbox, converters, flowdocument, typeconverter

How can i load a .txt file as `FlowDocument` to put it in a `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried google?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/loading-a-text-file-in-a-wpf-flowdocumentreader/

[Convert XAML to FlowDocument to display in RichTextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830987/convert-xaml-to-flowdocument-to-display-in-richtextbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2):

The following is a pretty simple method.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
     var range = new TextRange(Document.ContentStart, Document.ContentEnd);
     range.Load(fs, DataFormats.Text);
}
```