# How to save and open xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I'm tinkering with RichTextBox and flowdocuments.

After formatting text in RichTextBox, I am saving this file with **xaml** extension.

**RichTextBox:**

```
private void Save_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "XAML Format (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if(dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            TextRange range = new TextRange(rtbEditor.Document.ContentStart, rtbEditor.Document.ContentEnd);
            range.Save(fileStream, DataFormats.Xaml);
        }
    }
```

So I am get **xaml** file like this:

```
<Section>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run>Hello World</Run>
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph>
    <Run 
        FontFamily="Showcard Gothic">fdsafdsaf</Run>
    </Paragraph>
</Section>
```

Can i somehow parse this file into **flowdocument**? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830987/convert-xaml-to-flowdocument-to-display-in-richtextbox-in-wpf), but i don't know hot to get *xamlstring*. **StreamReader** didn't work. I need only wrap this **xaml** file into

```
<FlowDocument></FlowDocument>
```

After parsing into **flowdocument**. I want to do this:

**XAML:**

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer x:Name="viewer" />
```

**Code behind:**

```
viewer.document = *MyXamlFileAfterParsing*
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works:

```
FileStream xamlFile = File.Open("HUH.xaml", FileMode.Open);            
FlowDocument cds = new FlowDocument((Block)XamlReader.Load(xamlFile));                        
viewer.Document = cds;
xamlFile.Close();
```