# Windows forms: How do I add xaml to RichTextBox?

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

I want to show a formatted text in RichTextBox. I have an xaml as a source of formatted text.  How do I add xaml to RichTextBox?

PS  I'm using windows forms.

Comment: Check out this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449121/how-to-insert-xaml-into-richtextbox

Comment: Windows forms version of RichTextBox doesn't have property **Document**. That's why this solution doesn't work.

Comment: XAML is designed for use with WPF, not with Windows Forms.  You should be able to host a WPF control inside WinForms, however.  In any case, RichTextBox isn't the most appropriate control for XAML, since it uses RTF and not XHTML.